# How to sync daily the prod database to dev database in Azure SQL Server service?

Tags: replication, azure-sql-database, azure

I have two **Azure SQL Database**, prod and dev.

How can i daily replicate the `prod` database into `dev` database?
I have tried to automate it by exporting and importing the `BACPAC` file but it takes too long time.

There is **Data Sync** service in Azure but I am not sure if it works in one direction.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Geo-replication"

Go to your `prod` "SQL Database", Settings > Geo-replication

Configure your `dev` server/database to be readable "secondary"
All changes made at `prod` database , will be applied to `dev` database right away

Beware that you won't be able to change (insert,update,delete,create,etc) data at `dev` database while it is in the "readable secondary" role - only read (select)

Comment: as this is dev db, it should be able to be modifiable in order to make tests. But i don't want it these changes take effect on the prod. Here is my intention is to use most recent data in my dev environment.

Comment: if you want dev to be modifiable, then you can try using geo-replication for initial copying of data prod->dev (daily), and after it completes synchronizing (copying data prod->dev), disable/turn off geo-replication. This way dev has all latest data and is same as prod, and dev becomes modifiable right after you turn off geo-replication... and these tasks should be possible to automate using t-sql or powershell

Answer (score 1):

The Copy Database function could be an option for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#creating-a-copy

From my experience, it's much quicker than the BACPAC method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a  batch file that exports the database to BACPAC file and then imports into the dev database.

You will need [sqlpackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) utility and [sqlcmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) utility

The script is simple:

```
rem drop dev database 
sqlcmd -S myserver.database.windows.net -U username -P password -Q "DROP DATABASE [dev_database]"

rem Export production azure sql database to BACPAC file
sqlpackage.exe /TargetFile:"w:\temp\dev_db.bacpac" /Action:Export /SourceServerName:"myserver.database.windows.net" /SourceDatabaseName:"prod_database" /su:username /sp:password

rem Import bacpac file to dev database 
sqlpackage.exe /SourceFile:"w:\temp\dev_db.bacpac" /Action:Import /TargetServerName:"myserver.database.windows.net" /TargetDatabaseName:"dev_database" /tu:username /tp:password

rem change edition for dev database 
sqlcmd -S myserver.database.windows.net -U username -P password -Q "ALTER DATABASE [dev_database] MODIFY (EDITION='Basic');"
```

-

You can schedule this script in windows scheduler in your development computer.

Answer (score 0):

Data Sync seems to be the way. It has bidirectional sync
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql

The disadvantage is that it places some overhead on prod databases
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql#performance-impact